# OpenGL. How to invert X axis?

Tags: opengl

Yo guys. I working on online game, and all unit's movement will be processing on server side. And for server debugging I have to integrate physics engine into OpenGL, or OpenGL into physics engine, actually I just want to visualize unit's and other objects on server side using OpenGL.
But I faced with a problem. Inside game engine I have next axises orientation[image]

But in OpenGL world I see this orientation
[image]

This code clearly explains it. I just drawed axises

```
gl.glBegin(gl.GL_QUADS);
//z
gl.glColor3f(0,0,1);
gl.glVertex3f(-width,0,length);
gl.glColor3f(0,0,1);
gl.glVertex3f(width,0,length);
gl.glColor3f(0,0,0);
gl.glVertex3f(width,0,-length);
gl.glColor3f(0,0,0);
gl.glVertex3f(-width,0,-length);

//x
gl.glColor3f(1,0,0);
gl.glVertex3f(length,0,-width);
gl.glColor3f(1,0,0);
gl.glVertex3f(length,0,width);
gl.glColor3f(0,0,0);
gl.glVertex3f(-length,0,width);
gl.glColor3f(0,0,0);
gl.glVertex3f(-length,0,-width);

//y
gl.glColor3f(0,1,0);
gl.glVertex3f(-width,length,0);
gl.glColor3f(0,1,0);
gl.glVertex3f(width,length,0);
gl.glColor3f(0,0,0);
gl.glVertex3f(width,-length,0);
gl.glColor3f(0,0,0);
gl.glVertex3f(-width,-length,0);
gl.glEnd();
```

So colorized parts of lines are in positive part of world, and dark part are in negative. 
Watch next image pls

[image]

Do you see it? 
Here is camera and point of interest position when I get that screenshot

```
Camara: (-18.778223, 26.576332, -77.65113)  
Point of interest: (-18.571165, 26.34204, -76.672806)
```

So how can I invert X axis?

Comment: HolyBlackCat, maybe I just don't understand meaning of "towards", but +z is pointing in direction of camera view. Nearest part of Z axis is black.

Comment: Oh, I see. At first I didn't noticed your engine coordintae system.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose your matrix-related code looks like this:

```
...
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
// Matrix calculations
...
```

Then, you can do this:

```
...
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef(-1, 1, 1); // Each number represents scale for one axis
// Matrix calculations
...
```

Also you need to call `glFrontFace(GL_CW);` once after OpenGL initialization to compensate polygon winding direction inversion.

---

**But I recommend you to not do that and invert Z axis in your engine instead.**

It's easier when coordinate system in you engine is same as OpenGL one:

```
            +Y

          _______
         /  -Z   \
-X      /         \     +X
       /           \
      /     +Z      \
      """""""""""""""

            -Y
```

Comment: Nice art! unfortunately I can't change something in game engine, because have not source code =(